# Recover the state of Jframe1 when moved from JFrame1 and returning from Jframe 2

Tags: java, jframe, netbeans-8

I have a 2 frames, namely Jframe1 and Jframe2. I want that when I return from Jframe2 to Jframe1 after moving from Jframe1 to Jframe2. Jframe1 consists of a textfield and a forward button and Jframe2 consists of a backward button. I have set defaultCloseOperation as Hide. But it doesn't seems to work.

Coding for forward button

```
this.setVisible(false);     
new Jframe2().setVisible(true);
```

Coding for backward button

```
this.setVisible(false);   
new Jframe1().setVisible(true);
```

What is the solution of this?